# tomcat not creating access logs in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35001421/18573) answer and [springboot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) documentation to add the following in `application.properties`.

I can see these properties at `https://localhost:9999/actuator/configprops` and the requests I make at `https://localhost:9999/actuator/httptrace` but no access log file gets created.

I have to log4j2 logs files created in the same folder, so I do not think it is a file write problem or similar.

How can I debug this further?

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
```

Answer (score 7):

Access logs are getting created after I defined `server.tomcat.basedir` in `application.properties`. Its value seems to be relative to to where I am running it from.

catalina.base default value is a temporary directory in my $TMP, which is where the access logs get created without this setting

Comment: If you want a full example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62002598/8718377