# How to implement a validation layer on top login authentication in Spring with minimal changes to code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I want to add a validation layer on top of an existing authentication and authorisation layer in Spring for some my REST Controller. The validation will applicable for certain API only and I want to mark them with, say, some annotation over the controller method. This API requiring such validation will carry a parameter which will be checked with the value in the database (somewhat like the 2 step verification but this will be authorization for some API and only in special cases for eg. enter OTP for accessing sensitive data)

I tried using standard Spring AOP using @annotation point cut expression and it does not work on controllers. I am not sure but [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817236/spring-aop-around-controllers-does-not-work-when-request-input-are-invalid) suggests that point cut cannot be used on controller methods as they are already proxied (suggest me if i am wrong here).

I thought of using `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` but this doesn't seem right as it concerns with MVC not REST.

Using filters, i have a concern that how do i restrict to certain API only. Also, i need to access service layer to fetch some details to check if the authorisation is required and to fetch the data. Moreover, i don't want to increase the load for every request for making DB call one more time.

Is there any elegant/clean way of achieving this?

Comment: yes, use HandlerInterceptorAdapter like you wanted. It works for rest also. Edit: Actually i see that it's deprecated now but you can use AsyncHandlerInterceptor or HandlerInterceptor instead. HandlerInterceptor was implemented by HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Comment: also JWT tokens can solve issue with DB fetching